# How to trigger focus handler without actually focusing the element?

Tags: javascript

jQuery enables it like so:

```
$( "input" ).triggerHandler( "focus" );
```

How can I achieve the same without jQuery?

https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-javascript) - second answer and below I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `dispatchEvent` on the element for which you want `focus` to be triggered. See the 
docs and an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

```js
const event = new FocusEvent('focus', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});

const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

myInput.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```css
#myInput:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" onfocus="console.log('Input focused!');"/>
```

As you can see in the above code, the `console.log` statement is run based on the bound event to the `input` tag, but the element is not actually focused (because otherwise the input box would be red, which you can try by clicking on it).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I asked for. Unfortunately, it still focuses the input on my side. (I want to trigger internal functionality of a 3rd party component.) Your example clearly works, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Cheers, any other insight into the problem? I'd be happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getEventListeners(node)` function

In your case:
`console.log(getEventListeners(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]));`

You will get all the listeners, then you can filter those that are attached to the `focus` event

Comment: Please note this is a browser specific command, though for all I know edge may have started including it as well.